# Start week number from given date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have a table which stores customers data. Given that a week contains 7 days, I covet to be able to start the **week count from 1** *the next day* after each customer's `create_date` respectively. After which, bucket the cust_purchase_date in the appropriate week_number.

**the week number breakdown should be different for every customer**

```
 cust_id       create_date      cust_purchase_date     purchase_amount  
  111          7/5/2021            7/6/2021              85.00      
  111          7/5/2021            7/8/2021              25.00      
  111          7/5/2021            7/15/2021             35.00      
  111          7/5/2021            7/25/2021             15.00      
  222          7/9/2021            7/10/2021             10.00      
  222          7/9/2021            7/18/2021             25.00      
  222          7/9/2021            7/25/2021             31.00      
  222          7/9/2021            7/27/2021             41.00      
  333          7/11/2021           7/15/2021             51.00      
  333          7/11/2021           7/21/2021             65.00      
  444          7/15/2021           7/16/2021             100.00     
  444          7/15/2021           7/24/2021             78.00      
  444          7/15/2021           7/30/2021             87.00      
  555          8/20/2021           8/24/2021             71.00      
  555          8/20/2021           8/30/2021             55.00      
  555          8/20/2021           9/3/2021              36.00      
  555          8/20/2021           9/8/2021              25.00
```

Date Table (mocked - up):

```
cust_id  create_date  Wk 1 Start    Wk 1 End     Wk 2 Start   Wk 2 End    Wk 3 Start  Wk 3 End....
 111      7/5/2021     7/6/2021     7/12/2021    7/13/2021    7/19/2021   7/20/2021   7/26/2021...
 222      7/9/2021     7/10/2021    7/16/2021    7/17/2021    7/23/2021   7/24/2021   7/30/2021...
 333      7/11/2021    7/12/2021    7/18/2021    7/19/2021    7/25/2021   7/26/2021   8/1/2021...
 444      7/15/2021    7/16/2021    7/22/2021    7/23/2021    7/29/2021   7/30/2021   8/5/2021...
 555      8/20/2021    8/21/2021    8/27/2021    8/28/2021    9/3/2021    9/4/2021    9/10/2021...
```

Requested:

```
cust_id       create_date      cust_purchase_date     purchase_amount    week_number            
  111          7/5/2021            7/6/2021              85.00               1
  111          7/5/2021            7/8/2021              25.00               1
  111          7/5/2021            7/15/2021             35.00               2
  111          7/5/2021            7/25/2021             15.00               3
  222          7/9/2021            7/10/2021             10.00               1
  222          7/9/2021            7/18/2021             25.00               2
  222          7/9/2021            7/25/2021             31.00               3
  222          7/9/2021            7/27/2021             41.00               3
  333          7/11/2021           7/15/2021             51.00               1
  333          7/11/2021           7/21/2021             65.00               2
  444          7/15/2021           7/16/2021             100.00              1
  444          7/15/2021           7/24/2021             78.00               2
  444          7/15/2021           7/30/2021             87.00               3
  555          8/20/2021           8/24/2021             71.00               1
  555          8/20/2021           8/30/2021             55.00               2
  555          8/20/2021           9/3/2021              36.00               3
  555          8/20/2021           9/8/2021              25.00               3
```

Comment: Date difference in days with integer division by seven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
select abs('7/5/2020'::DATE - '7/15/2021'::DATE) / 7 as weeks;
 weeks 
-------
    53
```

Use abs() so order of date is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you sure that works once the dates span different years?

Comment: No, it will only extract the week number.

Comment: Then it doesn't work ;)

Comment: I think Belayers answer is probably what you need. :-) extract(purchace_date - creation_date) / 7.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the purpose of your date_table but it seems an attempt to predetermine the week number for each customer with a column for each week. The problem with this approach is how many weeks do you generate columns for? What happens when a customer makes a purchase 5 years (or more) after the `create_date`. *Further it is not necessary*.  Postgres allows [date subtraction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html) giving the number of days as an integer. Since your "week contains 7 days" simple division gives the week. (see [demo](http://54093ea99774b56b1e1b2150a6a0b3fc)).

```
select cust_id         
     , create_date   
     , purchase_date  
     , amount 
     , (purchase_date - create_date)/7 + 1 week_num
  from customer_purchases;
```